# Existing component throw: Unknown custom element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to use a component in another component. On the `created` event, I can log this component and it returns the good object. However for some reasons, the component doesn't seem to be included. VueJS do not understand the `validation` tag.

Any ideas?

```
<template>
  <main>
    <validation :validate="$v.email" :model="'email'"></validation> 
  </main>
</template>
<script>
  import { Validation } from 'components/helpers'

  export default {
    name: 'login',
    component: { Validation },
    created() {
      // it works. print the component with his path
      window.console.log(Validation)
    }
  }
</script>
```

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.

In `components/helpers` I have two file:

1) index.js

```
export { default as Validation } from './Validation'
```

2) Validation.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span class="form__validation" v-if="validate && !validate.required">Required</span>
        <template v-if="validation[model]">
            <span class="form__validation" v-for="error in validation[model].messages">{{ error }}</span>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'validation',
  data() {
    return {
      L: L
    }
  },
  props: ['model', 'validate'],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      validation: 'getValidation'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In your first code sample, you are registering the Validation component with `component: {}`(singular) instead of `components: {}` (plural) - could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `component` for `components` did the trick. Shame on me :)